# SVGKit iOS loading of image

Tags: ios, svgkit

I've imported SVGKit lib into my project and I would like to load svg image that I have stored in NSString like that:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ....
</svg>
```

When I try to load it via

```
SVGKImage* newImage = [SVGKImage imageWithContentsOfURL:svgUrl];
```

I get err because the url is nil, thats obvious because it isn't URL, but is there any method in library that I can use??

Comment: There is not enough information here. Why is the url nil?

Comment: Problem isn't that url is nil, but problem is how to load svg image stored in NSString thru SVGKit library methods... I have one idea to convert NSString to NSInputString and with that init SVGSource. This should probably work ...

Comment: Where is the file you want to load? Is it local or remote?

Comment: Its loaded from web and stored in NSString

Comment: So the `NSString` contains the SVG source?

Comment: Are you getting the SVG from a file?

Comment: Yes, SVG is stored as NSString

Comment: If you're loading from a file you can use `SVGKImage  initWithContentsOfFile:` where the parameter is the path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a NSURL object from the string representation of the URL, so:

```
NSString *strURL = "http://......";

NSURL *imageURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:strURL];

SVGKImage *svgImage = [SVGKImage imageWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
```

Does that help?

Comment: I know this approach, but I have only string representation of SVG itself not the url ... :(

Comment: Oh right, so you've got a SVG as an XML that you need to parse? I found this: http://t-machine.org/index.php/2012/12/31/svgkit-2013-usage/ which talks a bit about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
NSData* svgData = [svgSource dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
SVGKImage *svgImage = [SVGKImage imageWithData:svgData];
```

However, I suspect that what you should be doing is what Zhang is suggesting. In any case, you should make sure that when you download the data you do it off the main thread.

Comment: I would like to use this approach, but I get Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Method unsupported / not yet implemented by SVGKit' so this is dead end :(

Answer (score 0):

Using the SVGKit 2.x, you can use the [SVGKLayeredImageView](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SVGKit/1.0/Protocols/SVGLayeredElement.html) and load the image from URL: (My sample code in Swift Xcode 7.1)

1. In Interface Builder, drag a "View" into the your Scene.
2. Go to Identity Inspector and change that Custom Class of that view is 
   SVGKLayeredImageView
   (If the class is not available and you do not see it here, that means you do not import SVGKit the same version I have or do not [install](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) the framework properly)
3. Make outlet connection of that view then you should have

> @IBOutlet weak var svgImageView: SVGKLayeredImageView!

4. Usage

   ```
     if let url = NSURL(string: "http://your-svg-file-url"){
           if url.pathExtension!.lowercaseString == "svg" {

               svgImageView.image = SVGKImage(contentsOfURL: url)

           }
       }
   ```